# Converting Hard Drive from FDD to HDD mode without loss data

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, floppy

My hard drive cannot be partitioned.  In DiskGenius my disk is shown as FDD (floppy disk). Is there a method to convert FDD mode to HDD mode without loss of partitions and data? DiskGenius has such option but it say it would delete all partition and files.

I tried:

- Disk Management (Windows built-in tool): while resizing i get "The Parameter is Incorrect"
- AOMEI Partition Assistant: my disk is shown as few random weird partitions (file system "Other" and "Unallocated")
- GParted: I cannot resize (button is gray) and I get a warning:

  ```
  The device /dev/sda1 doesn't exist. 

  Unable to read the contents of this file system!
  Because of this some operations may be unavailable.

  The cause might be a missing software package.
  The following list of software packages is required for ntfs
  file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g
  ```

My drive: WD5000LPCX-24C6H0, 500GB. I can access its files on Windows and Parted Magic without problems.

Output of diskpart commands:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          232 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online           14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary            465 GB      0 B
```

output of lsblk:

```
root@dhcppc3:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
sdb       8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1    8:17   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb2    8:18   0 100,3G  0 part 
├─sdb3    8:19   0   480M  0 part 
└─sdb4    8:20   0   132G  0 part 
sdc       8:32   1  14,9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1    8:33   1  14,9G  0 part 
loop253   7:253  0  53,6M  0 loop 
loop254   7:254  0 315,3M  0 loop
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense... what kind of hard drive or computer is this? Can you show the output of `lsblk` in Linux (You menioned Gparted) or using diskpart what is the output of `list disk` and `list partition` commands?

Comment: Maybe some questions you might answer for insight are...  What behavior or errors did you get when you tried those programs?  Where did the drive come from?  When was last time you you were able to access the files on the drive; what OS or hardware was it accessible with?

Comment: @Damon I've edited my question.

Comment: @acejavelin added diskpart output

Comment: If you check the disk properties in Windows, is it am encrypted disk or volume? That could explain other utilities inability to see into the disk.

Comment: @acejavelin Nope. The only thing that I did with my drive was a removing all partitions but one and extending this one partition to the whole disk. I don't remember what tool I used.

Comment: Then at this point I would backup any data on that drive, wipe the partition table or use dd write zeros to the drive, then write a new partition table and start over, something is not standard. My 2¢ worth of advice.